# How to use nvidia-xconfig with 2 GPUs and one is not NVidia?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a cluster of machines running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS that are equipped with two graphic cards, a NVidia GeForce GT 240 (secondary) and a Matrox one (primary). Because it just seems to ignore the Matrox graphics card, `nvidia-xconfig` does not deem necessary to add a `BusID` field in my `/etc/X11/XF86Config` file, and I need to add it manually. Given that the BusID field changes from machine to machine, I'd be happy that `nvidia-xconfig` does the job automatically.

Is that possible to force `nvidia-xconfig` to specify the proper BusID in that particular case? Note that using the option `--enable-all-gpus` does not work!

Comment: Could you please provide your xorg.conf? This would really help me configuring my two cards.

Comment: @Damian: here you go!

Comment: Looks like that's an answer you've posted in your question? Edit it out and pop it as an answer then accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I came up with as a fix is to use `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` to obtain the BusID, and then feed it again to `nvidia-xconfig` to update the XF86Config file. Here is the script line that does that:

```
nvidia-xconfig --connected-monitor="CRT" --busid=`nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info | grep BusID | sed 's/PCI BusID : PCI:/PCI:/'`
```

Finally, my `XF86Config` file looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 240"
    BusID          "  PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "CRT"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: If your Nvidia card is connected via the DVI port which is more typical since the VGA should be connected to the motherboard's VGA port in order to see boot messages, then you need something like `nvidia-xconfig --connected-monitor="DFP" --busid="$(nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info | grep BusID | sed 's/PCI BusID : PCI:/PCI:/')"` instead.